# How to Open Cmd(Command Prompt) through C program

Tags: c++, c, dos

Actually, I want to execute DOS command by a C program and want to display the output of DOS command in my C Output Window.

**example:**

use "dir C:\" which displays output to C- program

Comment: You should use `pipe`, no idea how to do this in Windows, in UNIX systems you use `popen`. There must be some equivalent for this in Windows

Comment: Sorry, the pipe is needed only if you want to use the output in you program, forgot to mention that. Otherwise, you can use `system("..")`, as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To execute a command in the same `cmd.exe` window where your C program is running:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
.
.
.
system("dir C:\\");
```

To launch a separate windows, you need to call [`cmd.exe`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true):

```
system("cmd.exe /c dir c:\\");
```

(Note: I have not tested this one);

Comment: Does not work on windows 10 just outputs to same window.

Answer (score 3):

```
system("dir");
```

should dump in the current stdout

Answer (score 2):

But system() is evil. Here's why: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/ Make sure you give thorough thought before using it.